# Android Studio Error..Works on some devices and not others

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my error.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: com.rahulapps.voiceofmp, PID: 8980
>                                                                          java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
>                                                                              at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                              at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1616)
>                                                                              at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1587)
>                                                                              at
>   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4886)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4481)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4421)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:141)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
>                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

My app gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rahulapps.voiceofmp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/http-core-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/StartAppInAppPlus-2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')

}
```

Comment: Add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` to your dependencies.

Comment: not working sir..the app shows unfortunately .app has stopped. and if i am using lollipop version then it is working fine..

Comment: Try cleaning and building your project again.

Comment: Also, add this attribute to the application tag in manifest: `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`

Comment: add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`

Comment: whats your gradle version ?

Comment: min sdk is 16 and i am using device of version 19

Comment: if i am putting that code in manifest my json is not working..means i am not able to fetch data which is fetching in code already..@PrerakSola

Answer (score 0):

Its your GPS dependency.

- Use latest version
- Dont use the full google play services bundle. Just use components of what you need.
- And also try and always use specific versions instead of `+`.

Replace

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

With those of the following which you actually need:

```
Google+ com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.2
Google Account Login    com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2
Google Actions, Base Client Library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.2
Google Address API  com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.0.2
Google App Indexing com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.2
Google App Invites  com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.0.2
Google Analytics    com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.2
Google Cast com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.0.2
Google Cloud Messaging  com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2
Google Drive    com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:9.0.2
Google Fit  com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:9.0.2
Google Location, Activity Recognition, and Places   com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2
Google Maps com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2
Google Mobile Ads   com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2
Mobile Vision   com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.0.2
Google Nearby   com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:9.0.2
Google Panorama Viewer  com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:9.0.2
Google Play Game services   com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.0.2
SafetyNet   com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:9.0.2
Android Pay com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:9.0.2
Android Wear    com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.0.2
```

Read more in [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project).

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code in android in gradle:

```
aaptOptions{
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}
```